# Cancelling URLSessionStreamTask never calls the completionHandler with NSURLErrorCancelled (on macOS)

Tags: swift, macos, nsurlsession, osx-elcapitan

I have a trivial playground and a simple TCP server on localhost. All I want to do is be able to cancel a URLSessionStreamTask that already has a readData operation enqueued. What's crazy is that this exact playground works totally fine for iOS or tvOS but not for macOS.

On iOS/tvOS I get the following output:

```
Resuming...
Cancelling...
After cancel call
Victory! The session task was properly cancelled!
```

On macOS (10.11) the "Victory!" message never gets printed.

Here is the playground:

```
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

let task = URLSession.shared.streamTask(withHostName: "localhost", port: 12345)

task.readData(ofMinLength: 1, maxLength: 1024, timeout: 0) { (data, atEOF, error) in
    if let error = error as? NSError {
        if error.code == NSURLErrorCancelled {
            print("Victory! The session task was properly cancelled!")
        }
    }
}

print("Resuming...")
task.resume()

print("Cancelling...")
task.cancel()
print("After cancel call")
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Am I missing something here? I am using XCode 8 (beta 4). Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This might be a CPU speed issue.  Specifically, the session may have already read all the data from the stream and stored it locally, waiting for your app to request it, before your app even has time to cancel the connection.  Does this problem also occur if your server sends... say a gigabyte of data?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is old by now but under 10.12 this seems to work correctly.

```
Resuming...
Cancelling...
After cancel call
Victory! The session task was properly cancelled!
```